# A twisted triple paradox

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation, thought-experiment

As far as I know when a person travels with some velocity relative to other person time runs slower to him relative to the other person (Because the velocity of light is constant in all frame of reference). This I have understood from twin paradox. But this becomes complex to understand when it is more than twins.

For example, here is a thought experiment,

Imagine there is a huge treadmill covering the entire circumference of the earth and there is a vehicle situated on that treadmill belt. Now there are three twins( twin A; twin B; twin C). So here twin C gets into the vehicle, twin B hold on to the treadmill belt(so that he moves along with the belt) and twin A is standing in the ground(stationary).

Now the vehicle starts to move in 99% of $c$ (speed of light) and the treadmill starts to run in the opposite direction with the same speed of the vehicle so that the vehicle appears to be stationary to twin A.

So here blindly applying the theory which was applied in twin paradox time running for twin B should be slower than the time running for twin A. And time running for twin C should be slower than that of twin B. But now if we suddenly neglected that treadmill from our experiment(Let's say it becomes invisible) now this makes no sense as the vehicle looks stationary to twin A and so the time should run in equal speed for them. So what will actually happen in this thought experiment?

Comment: The fact that the conveyor belt is _circular_ makes this a bit trickier. Would you be just as happy with an answer where the conveyor belt is straight?

Comment: Do you mean triplets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time dilation effects are not transitive. According to an inertial observer, any clock moving relative to that observer will be observed to be ticking slower. Therefore, A and C will observe the clock of B to be slower than their clocks. B will observe the clocks of A and C to be ticking slower than their clock. A and C are in the same inertial reference frame, so they see each of their clocks ticking at the same rate.

You have to pick a frame and then stay in that frame. You cannot compare different time dilations for different frames and hold them all to be true at once. It all depends on the reference frame.

Also, since A and C are in the same intertial reference frame, this is basically the just the original twin paradox (it's not a triplet paradox).

Comment: If we consider that A and C are in the same reference frame then B will move in different speeds wrt A and wrt C, right? which means the time dilation should differ wrt A and wrt C? But this makes no sense and even if we consider the amount of time dilation to be the same wrt A&C then Speed of Light will not be in constant for all frames of reference, isn't?

Comment: @multiversal both A and C will observe B to be moving at the same speed.

Answer (score 1):

$\let\g=\gamma \let\D=\Delta$
@Aaron Stevens *Each observer will view the clock moving relative to
them as ticking slower. Are you saying this is not the case?* Excuse
me, Aaron, for my delay. I can't keep up with all threads where I
would like to say something.

I'm replying to your question-comment with an answer since I'm not able
to stay within limits of a comment, be it a serial one.

It is the case if properly qualified. It isn't the case if naively
stated, as I see in most cases. I've been following SE for slightly
more than 3 months, and remember several answers of mine where I already
had to explain what should be meant when statements such that are
made. I also said that I don't like the term "time dilation", just
because it is prone to misunderstandings and confusions. Nor I like
"clocks going slower" and worse of all "time (itself) going slower. Of
course I don't expect that anybody, let alone a newcomer, may know
those statements, so I'll go to repeat.

And now for the positive side. The issue of time dilation, correctly
understood, refers to two *events* (of timelike separation), say E, F
and to two (inertial) reference frames. Given E and F, there is a frame
$K_0$ where they happen *at the same place*. In any other frame $K$ the
same events happen instead at different space positions. This sets the
stage.

Now for measurements. Let $\D t_0$ be the time interval between E and
F, measured by a clock in $K_0$, set just in the place where both events
are happening. Let $\D t$ the time measured in $K$. But here an
important clarification is in order. The time measurement in $K$ can't
be done *with just one clock*. Since E and F happen in different
places, two clocks are needed, one for each place. And of course
these clocks must have been previously *synchronized*. It is tacitly
understood that synchronization is effected "à la Einstein", i.e.
through a light signal (whose velocity is assumed known) between
clocks.

All this being set, it can be shown that always $\D t>\D t_0$. More
precisely, $\D t=\g\,\D t_0$, $\g$ being the usual Lorentz
factor for the speed $v$ of $K$ relative to $K_0$.

So you see why we can't simply say "A sees B's clock running slower
and viceversa". When one talks about A's clock he's implicitly using
events related to *two readings of A's clock*, so that $K_0$ is A's
frame, $K$ is B's. And when one switches to B's clock two other
events are in action, related to B's clock. Now $K_0$ has become B's
frame, $K$ is A's.

A final note. Twins paradox in another matter, I don't want to touch here.

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I know when a person travels with some velocity relative
>   to other person time runs slower to him relative to the other person

If you really read this somewhere, the author is guilty of having led
you into a deep misunderstanding. There is no need of your gigantic
treadmill to see it. A simple question is enough.

Let me call A the first person in the quotation above, B the other
person. You say A travels with some velocity relative to B, then time
runs slower to A relative to B's time.

I say: if A travels wrt B, then B travels wrt A. So it should be B's
time to run slower. Since both things can't happen together, there is
a contradiction. Two possibilities arise:

- Your original statement is wrong.
- Special relativity is inconsistent.

What do you believe the truth is?

Comment: Each observer will view the clock moving relative to them as ticking slower. Are you saying this is not the case?

Comment: @AaronStevens:  The OP says (incorrectly) that time runs slower for B than for A.  Elio says (correctly and relevantly) that this is nonsense.  You say (correctly but much less relevantly) that each observer views the clock moving relative to  him as ticking slower --- which is an entirely different statement.   What ever would make you think that Elio is denying this statement?

Comment: @WillO I guess I got mixed up by the wording here. What do you mean that my statement is not relevant? Do you mean not relevant to this answer or not relevant to the OPs question?

Comment: third possibility, A sees B's clock running slower and viceversa

Comment: @Wolphramjonny That is what I was trying to say as well.

Comment: @AaronStevens Yes, I agree with you and do not understand the answer, unless it is plain wrong as I suspect

Comment: @AaronStevens:  I mean not relevant to the answer.  The answer seems to me to be completely clear and on-target and goes right to the heart of why the OP's original "understanding" cannot be correct, under any reasonable interpretation of the phrase "time runs slower".  It completely resolves the paradox as stated by the OP.  I don't see any interpretation under which it denies (or even appears to deny) your correct statement about clock rates.

Comment: @WillO As I said, I must have gotten the wording in the answer mixed up.

Comment: @AaronStevens :  It happens to all of us. :)

Comment: @WillO My question is how come an ordinary twin paradox becomes more complicated just by adding a car moving in the opposite direction. Hence why should the fact that B's clock runs slower than A's(because B is moving) is incorrect just because there is the presence of C. I mean how is that C affecting the system?

Comment: @multiversal: And elio gave you your answer.

Comment: @WillO Yes, I got the point that we must stick to only one frame of reference. But what will be the result of the system(my thought experiment) after running for some time? Who will be aged more? Who will be aged lesser?

Comment: @multiversal:  The  answers to your questions are frame-dependent.  "How old is Bob on Alice's twentieth birthday?" has one answer in Bob's frame and a different answer in Alice's. Which frame of reference do you want to "stick to"?